# How to see if a string in a pandas column appears in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, called `Matches` with a column called `MatchIDs`. This contains a selection of Match IDs as below:

```
Man CityTottenham
BoltonMan City
Man CityWigan
NewcastleMan City
ChelseaMan City
Man CityWest Ham
Man UnitedMan City
Man CityFulham
Man CityBlackpool
```

What I am after:

In another column of this `Matches` DataFrame, for each ID, a binary output of 0 or 1, if the ID appears in an entirely separate DataFrame, call it `Rivals` (not sure if a list/dictionary would be better).

An example:
So in the separate DataFrame `Rivals`, there would be:

```
Man CityTottenham
Man UnitedMan City
ChelseaMan City
```

And for the original DataFrame `Matches`, a 1 is awarded if the MatchID appears in `Rivals`, a 0 if not. The correct output is the right hand column:

```
Man CityTottenham     1
BoltonMan City        0
Man CityWigan         0
NewcastleMan City     0
ChelseaMan City       1
Man CityWest Ham      0
Man UnitedMan City    1
Man CityFulham        0
Man CityBlackpool     0
```

So `Man UnitedMan City` = 1, because it appears in the `Rivals` DataFrame, whereas `NewcastleMan City` = 0.

I have tried and struggled to find the right way of doing this and would really appreciate any help!

Hopefully, the explanation is clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check values of column `MatchIDs` in second `df` called `Rivals`, last cast boolean mask to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
Matches['new'] = Matches['MatchIDs'].isin(Rivals['MatchIDs']).astype(int)
```

Also if values are in `list`:

```
Matches['new'] = Matches['MatchIDs'].isin(L).astype(int)
```