# Find Dataframe field in another frame and flag it if found

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame wants to compare some fields between two and if filed found in both the data frame then flag it to true else false.
here StoreId And PartyCode is a composite key.

**Code:**

```
df1 = DataFrame({'StoreId': [1, 2, 3], 'PartyCode': ['a', 'b', 'c'],'anotherfiled': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df2 = DataFrame({'StoreId': [1, 5,4], 'PartyCode': ['a', 'b','d']})
df1.isin(df2)
```

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: @jezrael why did you reopen with no comment or discussion? This is obviously a duplicate and adding `.astype(int)` is not a reason to reopen

Comment: @cs95 - hmmm, because part time dupe, please find better match and I close answer.

Comment: @jezrael how about [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47498769/), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55790602/), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842060)  all by you... woooow... this was from page 1 if you need more duplicates I can help you find them

Comment: @cs95 - Why more? One is absolutely enough.

Comment: @jezrael, i have to compare tow fields StoreId and PartyCode Combination like composite key

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @jezrael, you marked  as a duplicate but non of above solutions resolves my problem. its related to multiple fields comparision

Comment: @JunedAnsari - Can you change data for mcve? Because now solution bellow working perfectly with sample data.

Comment: @jezrael, now check updated question, below solution will not work, i have changes storeid from 2 to 5  in df2

Comment: @JunedAnsari - match is by `PartyCode`, so still working nice

Comment: @jezrael just in case you're unaware: you can edit the duplicate target list without reopening and reclosing the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - I reopened first dupe, so I closed, because I think dupe. Unfortunately now I cannot reopen

Comment: @jezrael I saw that you closed it again which is why I left the comment. Why would you want to reopen again?

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Because OP reported not dupe. What is correct way? Reopen?

Comment: We can tell @cs95 that OP thinks the dupes are insufficient so he should look for new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the column you want to check.

```
df1.loc[:, "flag"] = df1['PartyCode'].isin(df2['PartyCode'])
df1
```

So your output is the same as you requested.

```
    StoreId PartyCode   anotherfiled    flag
0     1       a            x            True
1     2       b            y            True
2     3       c            z            False
```

Comment: And from here the very trivial fix to get the expected output is `df1['PartyCode'].isin(df2['PartyCode']).astype(int)`

Comment: what about StoreId? because StoreId and PartyCode is composite key